# O que Threads compartilham ao fazerem chamadas Http?

Tags: c#, thread, http-request, scraping

**O problema:** não consigo fazer login em um site mais de uma vez em `Threads` diferentes.

Minha aplicação é um `Console application`.
Se eu abrir **vários executável**, cada um consegue fazer **login com sucesso** em **uma `Thread`**, somente **a primeira**. Acredito que isso exclui vários problemas que eu poderia ter relacionados ao site que estou acessando, pois os vários `Consoles` abertos utilizam as mesmas credenciais(usuário), estão sendo executados na mesma máquina e são abertos ao mesmo tempo. Portanto **o site permite mais de uma sessão** no mesmo usuário.

Estou usando **a mesma solução** para vários sites e ela **funcionou na maioria** que precisei fazer isso. Os sites não tem relação entre si e não me importo com qual tecnologia utilizam(não acho pertinente, mas posso verificar se for preciso).

As `Threads` são iniciadas com `new Thread(IniciaTarefa).Start(argumentos);`. O método `IniciaTarefa`  é estático, mas dentro ele instancia uma outra classe que não possui nada estático. E é esta outra classe que faz as requisições.

A cada requisição é instanciado um novo `request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;`, apesar que todas as requisições de uma mesma `Thread` compartilham o mesmo `CookieContainer` para manter a sessão.

**Aceito qualquer dica** sobre o que eu possa investigar, porque não tenho ideia de qual pode ser o problema, já revisei e tentei fazer diversas alterações no código, mas o problema persiste.
Se for preciso posso colocar trechos de código específicos, mas não sei o que pode ser pertinente.

Comment: Você verificou se há diferenças nas requisições de cada thread usando algum programa de fora? Como o Fiddler? http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

O problema está muito aberto, pode ser muitas coisas cada site pode gerenciar a autenticação de formas diferentes...

Answer (score 0):

O problema é o `CookieContainer` que está sendo compartilhado pelas Threads...
Quando você efetua o login, o site que você acesso grava um cookie no seu navegador (neste caso, o cookie fica gravado no CookieContainer) e é através dele que o site consegue identificar que você é você, pelo que você disse, o CookieContainer está sendo reutilizado pelas diversas Threads do mesmo processo, fazendo com que o login ocorra na primeira e da segunda em diante o site já identifique que você está logado exatamente pelo motivo de reutilizar o cookieContainer.
Experimente criar um `CookieContainer` por requisição, assim como você faz com `WebRequest.Create`